# Windows Firewall blocking SMB after a period of time

Tags: windows-10, networking, smb, windows-firewall, windows-domain

I have an issue with a restricted terminal machine running Windows 10 that I hope someone can shed some light on. This is on the domain and is restricted in Windows Firewall to only allow Google Chrome access to the WAN via Public connections (the VPN connection) on the machine. No other applications are allowed to access the Internet on the Domain or Public connections. There is a requirement for the machine to be able to access an SMB share on the DC as well. After a few hours of being connected to the VPN the mapped drive changes to disconnected. When the VPN connection is disconnected the mapped drive reconnects and the VPN can then be reconnected again. However, after a few hours the mapped drive will be disconnected again.

The setup:

- Windows 10 Professional joined to domain
- NIC set to Domain network
- VPN connection set to Public network
- Windows Defender Firewall Advanced Security set as follows

  - Inbound connections: Block (default)
  - Outbound connections: Allow (default)
  - Outbound policy: Chrome on Public Profile = Allowed

I have added all of the File and Printer Sharing template rules with full allow but the issue still happens.

With the Inbound connections set to Allow (default) or the firewall turned off, I don't have this issue, so it's definitely the firewall blocking it.

My presumption, based on the period of time it takes before the mapped drive disconnects, is that there is a authentication token that expires and the machine attempts to re-authenticate with the DC and this request is blocked. I've done a lot of reading into this but I can't find out what port or protocol that uses, or even if that is the issue.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT

route print while access to the SMB share is possible:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  7...00 ff 38 6b 39 56 ......Private Internet Access Network Adapter
 11...00 15 5d 02 69 0b ......Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
 15...00 ff ec 05 05 ae ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.7    281
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       xx.xx.xx.1      xx.xx.xx.15      3
       10.0.0.243  255.255.255.255       xx.xx.xx.1      xx.xx.xx.15      3
       xx.xx.xx.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
      xx.xx.xx.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
     xx.xx.xx.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
   46.246.122.183  255.255.255.255      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.7     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       xx.xx.xx.1      xx.xx.xx.15      3
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
      192.168.2.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1  Default 
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  7    259 fe80::/64                On-link
  7    259 fe80::cd9b:86ec:b0fd:8ef5/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  7    259 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

And after it is disconnected:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  7...00 ff 38 6b 39 56 ......Private Internet Access Network Adapter
 11...00 15 5d 02 69 0b ......Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
 15...00 ff ec 05 05 ae ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.7    281
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       xx.xx.xx.1      xx.xx.xx.15      3
       10.0.0.243  255.255.255.255       xx.xx.xx.1      xx.xx.xx.15      3
       xx.xx.xx.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
      xx.xx.xx.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
     xx.xx.xx.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
   46.246.122.183  255.255.255.255      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.7     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       xx.xx.xx.1      xx.xx.xx.15      3
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
      192.168.2.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       xx.xx.xx.15    259
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.7    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1  Default 
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  7    259 fe80::/64                On-link
  7    259 fe80::cd9b:86ec:b0fd:8ef5/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  7    259 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Note: have changed the local VPN IP address to xx for privacy

This is the error I get when trying to access the mapped drive

```
[Window Title]
Location is not available

[Content]
I:\ is not accessible.

The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.


[OK]
```

A few people have been commenting on this to help and going down the route of tunnelling on the VPN. Just to be clear, this is nothing to do with that, as my VPN connection doesn't tunnel all of the traffic through it and with Windows Firewall turned off it works without issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Most VPN's are configured so that ALL outgoing traffic goes via the VPN. That by itself would be enough too loose connection to the domain/share. Are you sure that isn't the case here? Is the share actually reachable when the VPN is on?  (Don't trust the icon state. Actually try to USE the share to verify.)

Comment: Hi Tonny,

Yes, when the VPN is connected I can fully browse and read/write on the mapped drive. It's only after a few hours that it disconnects. If the firewall is turned off it never disconnects.

Comment: Next time that this happens, can you verify that the computers clock is still in sync with the clock on other domain machines? (There shouldn't be more than 3 minutes difference between clocks.) I'm thinking that somehow the PC clock isn't syncing with the domain. (Either drift,because of no updates from domain, or synched with another time-source from the internet.) Clock offset would prevent refreshing session-token.

Comment: Does the disconnection happen after a period where the mapped drive is not used (idle)?

Comment: @Tonny the clock remains in sync

Comment: @harrymc It happens regardless of if it's being used or idle

Comment: It's unclear for me if the share is reached via the VPN, or if the share comes from another network than that of the VPN.

Comment: @harrymc the share isn't via the VPN, the share is on the local DC

Comment: Could you [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1709732/edit) your post and add to it the output of `route print` before and after the disconnection happens. Also, have you checked the settings of the VPN server?

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with the question,  but when my VPN is active (F5) it tries to route all traffic through the VPN ... after activating the VPN I always use the command "route delete 192.168.0.0" to remove the traffic of my home network from the VPN routing table

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the original post with the requested information. There is no difference.

Comment: @zentrunix thanks for the comment, but this is not related to tunnelling through the VPN, it's a Windows Firewall issue.